# Ubuntu, ElementaryOS and Windows Grub Broken

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, windows, elementary

The other day, I decided that, in addition to Ubuntu, I'd like to try ElementaryOS. So, I made another partition, and installed on that partition (sda5). In the installer, there was a box that said to choose the bootloader installation drive. So, I picked sda6 (my Ubuntu partition) so that it would merge with my existing grub. Now, I had no idea if this would work, but it seemed like it would make sense.

Anyways, it didn't work, and that's why I'm here. My computer default boots to Windows (that is, if I don't do anything when I press the power button, it'll boot to Windows). I want to keep this functionality. Normally, I would go and select the boot device, and then grub would come up and I could boot Ubuntu. So, I want to also be able to select ElementaryOS instead of Ubuntu. However, when I select the boot device that used to give me grub, it says `error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found` and shows me the grub rescue prompt (an image is below). Now, I figured out how to boot back into ubuntu. I have to type this:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt6)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

and it takes me back to my grub screen where I can pick Ubuntu. How can I make it so that I don't have to go through the grub rescue prompt, and put ElementaryOS on the grub menu. Furthermore, I ***DO NOT*** want grub to replace the default bootloader that boots Windows if I don't press anything.

Thanks, and sorry if this is badly explained. I'll be happy to clarify. The image of the grub prompt is below:

[image: grub rescue prompt]

EDIT: Link to boot-repair summary report http://paste.ubuntu.com/8792369/

Comment: If you have a gpt partitioned drive and Windows you must be booting in UEFI mode to boot Windows. Did you install both Ubuntu and Elementary in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? If you installed elementary in BIOS mode and put grub into the partition boot sector of the Ubuntu partition that would be a BIOS boot? Very confused. Best to see details. Post link to summary report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'll go ahead and make the report but in the meantime, I think I installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode and elementary in UEFI mode. Is that an issue?

Comment: @oldfred The link to the report is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8792369/

Comment: Yes, that is an issue, either put everything in BIOS mode or everything in UEFI mode.

Comment: It looks like you only have Windows in UEFI, and everything in BIOS. And somehow you have grub legacy installed to partition boot sectors? Ubuntu changed to grub2 back with version 9.10, five years ago. HP are not partitcularily UEFI dual boot friendly but many make it work with various work arounds. I did not think grub legacy worked with gpt partitioned drives? I would use Boot-Repair and do the full uninstall and reinstall of grub2. You could also reinstall grub2 in UEFI boot mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: I managed to make it work after running `grub-install --force /dev/sda6` and `grub-install --force /dev/sda` which were the ElementaryOS and Ubuntu Partitions. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work after running grub-install --force /dev/sda6 and grub-install --force /dev/sda which were the ElementaryOS and Ubuntu Partitions. Thanks for all the help!